# Regression / Probability should give one number!

Tags: machine-learning, statistics-in-media

This may be a strange question. I work as a data scientist for a Media company. My job revolves around predicting the expected "Reach" and number of views an ad will have based on mining historical data. I have used a variety of regressions (nonlinear, logistic) and Bayesian probability techniques. Without getting into too much detail, I work for a "business-type" boss, who doesn't understand the technicalities of anything of which I am doing. So, when he takes my report and gives it to a potential client, he **insists** that he wants ONE NUMBER. He doesn't want an upper bound / lower bound estimate on the regression output, does not want or care about an $R^2$ or $MSE$, he doesn't even understand any of the latter. Further, with Bayesian probabilities, he always wants me to give him one number, even though it is only correct to say that the probability of having $x$ views is $p$, and so forth. He claims that this is how it is simply done in the advertising industry, which I cannot fathom, since all of the advertising models are done using similar techniques. Are all statisticians/data scientists bending to the will of their boss, and simply giving one number?

If anyone has any recommendations or literature showing that this is in fact NOT the way it is done in the advertising world, I would very much appreciate that.

Thanks!

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to comment on the post, but I need to ask- Will not a simple average of the range corresponding to your upper and lower bound should do the trick? I mean you have already got the range of number of clicks, just take an average and that should be your one number.

Comment: Hi. You can't just give one number in this case, as most of the data we are dealing with corresponds to distributions that are bimodal or multimodal, pulling out a single average has no interpretive power.